# How to filter a REST API row response by a value of the row with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I configured a REST API POST Request that connects to an Oracle Service Cloud  and it receives the response in the following json format:

```
{"count":16,"name":"Report Name","columnNames":["Connection","Complete Name","Login ID","Login Time","Logout Time","IP Direction"],"rows":[["PGALICHI","Robert The IT Guy","3205","2018-01-25 08:52:23","2018-01-25 15:00:50","201.255.56.151"],["PGALICHI","Lucas The other IT Guy","3204","2018-01-25 08:52:21","2018-01-25 15:00:51","201.255.56.151"]],"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://web--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/analyticsReportResults"},{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://web--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/analyticsReportResults"},{"rel":"describedby","href":"https://web--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/metadata-catalog/analyticsReportResults","mediaType":"application/schema+json"}]}
```

This information will be the input for a script that will print just the rows, what I need now is, first, sort all the rows by "Login Time", and next, to filter all the values with a "Login Time" equal or earlier than a variable that will have the value of the last "Login Time".

This is an example of the code I use now to get only the rows:

```
class OracleORNHandler:

def __init__(self,**args):
    pass

def __call__(self, response_object,raw_response_output,response_type,req_args,endpoint):
    if response_type == "json":        
        output = json.loads(raw_response_output)
        for row in output["rows"]:
            print_xml_stream(json.dumps(row))                      
    else:
        print_xml_stream(raw_response_output)
```

Comment: your JSON string has issues, fix it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see it when I posted it, thanks.

Comment: Again date is enclosed by single quotes and then double quotes, even if I replace `'` with `''` I got below error on `json.loads` : *json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 284 (char 283)*

Comment: There is `,` missing near `3205` and dates to be enclosed with double quotes only

Answer (score 0):

This needs more coding. However I will explain the logic approach. 
You may want to vary the coding approach a little.

1. Load the string into a dictionary.

*Fixed string*

```
json_out = '{"count":16,"name":"Report Name","columnNames":["Connection","Complete Name","Login ID","Login Time","Logout Time","IP Direction"],"rows":[["PGALICHI","Robert The IT Guy","3205","2018-01-25 08:52:23","2018-01-25 15:00:50","201.255.56.151"],["PGALICHI","Lucas The other IT Guy","3204","2018-01-25 08:52:21","2018-01-25 15:00:51","201.255.56.151"]],"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://web--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/analyticsReportResults"},{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://web--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/analyticsReportResults"},{"rel":"describedby","href":"https://web--tst1.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.4/metadata-catalog/analyticsReportResults","mediaType":"application/schema+json"}]}'

dic_json = json.loads(json_out)
```

2. Convert the `rows` into a **dictionary**

Login Time is used as value as we will need it for sorting later.

Use `datetime` for converting string to date

```
from datetime import datetime
rows_list = dic_json['rows']
d = dict()

for x in rows_list:
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(x[4], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    d[x.__str__()] = datetime_object
```

**Note** : Since login time may or not be unique I chose whole list to be key
Even not sure login id is unique here.

3. Use `collections.OrderedDict` for sorting on time.;

i.e

```
import collections
# sort by time i.e dictionary values
od2 =collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
```

4. Filter values based on date-time condition.

**Input_time**
    `date_time_req = datetime.strptime('2018-01-25 08:52:23', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

```
for y in od2.keys():
    if od2[y] <= date_time_req:
        print(y)
```

This output is string , you can trim and convert it back to a list.